# Executing a .exe using powershell to multiple remote server

Tags: powershell, remote-server, sccm

I am trying to upgrade all endpoint with latest version of SCCM agent using installing them from a server through powershell script.  All the commands are running except `Invoke-command`.

```powershell
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force

$Comps = Get-Content C:\sccm_client_latest\SCCMAgentinstall_script\Computers.txt

Foreach ($comp in $Comps)
{       
    $b = Test-Connection $comp -Quiet -Count 2

    if ($b -eq 'true') 
    { 
        Copy-Item C:\sccm_client_latest\SCCM_v2111_Client -Destination \\$comp\c$\temp -Recurse -force
        timeout /t 120

        New-PSSession -ComputerName $comp
        invoke-command -ComputerName $comp -ScriptBlock {
            & 'C:\Temp\SCCM_v2111_Client\ccmsetup.exe' /mp:server.example.com SMSSITECODE=P01 SMSMP=server.example.com DNSSUFFIX=example.com
        } 

        Start-Sleep -Seconds 120
    }
}
```

Comment: `New-PSSession -ComputerName $comp` is unnecessary since you're passing `-ComputerName $comp` to `Invoke-Command`.  Is `Invoke-Command` generating any errors or other side-effects (e.g. log files), or it just does nothing?  I assume the user executing the script has access to the `C$` share and remoting sessions of the target computer?

Comment: The user who is executing the command has access to establish remote session to remote server. No error is getting generated in powershell when I am running this in ISE mode. User also has access to C$ share.
user can execute rest of the command except 'invoke-command' but no error is popping up as well.

Comment: Is `ccmsetup.exe` expected to produce output after success or failure?  Try putting `Get-Date` inside your `[ScriptBlock]` on the lines before and after your call to `ccmsetup.exe` and see if it at least outputs that.

Comment: I did not get it properly when actually you are trying add. Could you help with the full command.

also if I kick off the script in local computer removing '-ComputerName $comp' part, this script is working fine.

Is ccmsetup.exe expected to produce output after success or failure? : it should update the logs as well agent version, which is not happening.

Comment: Remove `New-PSSession -ComputerName $comp` and try just `Invoke-Command -ComputerName $comp -ScriptBlock { Get-Date }` and see if that works.  If so, then after `Get-Date` try adding your `ccmsetup.exe` command followed by another `Get-Date` and see how many `[DateTime]` instances are output.